# MySQL: database structure choice - big data - duplicate data or bridging

Tags: mysql, bigdata, schema

We have a 90GB MySQL database with some very big tables (more than 100M rows). We know this is not the best DB engine but this is not something we can change at this point.

Planning for a serious refactoring (performance and standardization), we are thinking on several approaches on how to restructure our tables.

The data flow / storage is currently done in this way:

- We have one table called articles, one connection table called article_authors and one table authors
- One single author can have 1..n firstnames, 1..n lastnames, 1..n emails
- Every author has a unique parent (unique_author), except if that author is the parent

The possible data query scenarios are as follows:

- Get the author firstname, lastname and email for a given article
- Get the unique authors.id for an author called John Smith
- Get all articles from the author called John Smith

The current DB schema looks like this:
[image]

**EDIT: The main problem with this structure is that we always duplicate similar given_names and last_names.**

We are now hesitating between two different structures:

1. Large number of tables, data are split and there are connections with IDs. No duplicates in the main tables: articles and authors. Not sure how this will impact the performance as we would need to use several joins in order to retrieve data, example:

[image: 1]

2. Data is split among a reasonable number of tables with duplicate entries in the table article_authors (author firstname, lastname and email alternatives) in order to reduce the number of tables and the application code complexity. One author could have 10 alternatives, so we will have 10 entries for the same author in the article_authors table:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current schema is probably the best.  The middle table is a many-to-many mapping table, correct?  That can be made more efficient by following the tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Rewrite #1 smells like "over-normalization".  A big waste.

Rewrite #2 has some merit.  Let's talk about phone_number instead of last_name because it is rather common for a person to have multiple phone_numbers (home, work, mobile, fax), but unlikely to have multiple names.  (Well, OK, there are pseudonyms for some authors).

It is *not* practical to put a bunch of phone numbers in a cell; it is much better to have a separate table of phone numbers linked back to whoever they belong to.  This would be 1:many.  (Ignore the case of two people sharing the same phone number -- due to sharing a house, or due to working at the same company.  Let the number show up twice.)

I don't see why you want to split firstname and lastname.  What is the "firstname" of "J. K. Rowling"?  I suggest that it is not useful to split names into first and last.

A single author would have a unique "id".  `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT` is good for such.  "J. K. Rowling" and "JK Rowling" can both link to the same `id`.

**More**

I think it is very important to have a unique `id` for each author.  The `id` can be then used for linking to books, etc.

You have pointed out that it is challenging to map different spellings into a single id.  I think this should be essentially a separate task with separate table(s).  And it is this task that you are asking about.

That is, split the database split, *and* split the tasks in your mind, into:

- one set of tables containing stuff to help deduce the correct `author_id` from the inconsistent information provided from the outside.
- one set of tables where `author_id` is known to be unique.

(It does not matter whether this is one versus two `DATABASEs`, in the MySQL sense.)

The mental split helps you focus on the two different tasks, plus it prevents some schema constraints and confusion.  None of your proposed schemas does the clean split I am proposing.

Your main question seems to be about the first set of tables -- how do turn strings of text ("JK Rawling") into a specific id.  At this point, the question is *first* about algorithms, and only *secondly* about the schema.

That is, the tables should be designed to *support* the algorithm, not to *drive* it.  Furthermore, when a new provider comes along with some strange new text format, you may need to modify the schema - possibly adding a special table for that provider's data.  So, don't worry about making the perfect schema this early in the game; plan on running `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` next month or even next year.

If a provider is consistent in spelling, then a table with (`provider_id`, `full_author_name`, `author_id`) is probably a good first cut.  But that does not handle variations of spelling, new authors, and new providers.  We are getting into gray areas where human intervention will quickly be needed.  Even worse is the issue of two authors with the same name.

So, design the algorithm with the assumption that simple data is easily and efficiently available from a database.  From that, the schema design will somewhat easily flow.

Another tip here...  Some degree of "brute force" is OK for the hard-to-match cases.  Most of the time, you can easily map name strings to `author_id` very efficiently.

It *may* be easier to fetch a hundred rows from a table, them massage them in your algorithm in your app code.  (SQL is rather clumsy for algorithms.)

Comment: Thanks @Rick James! I will answer here in three different comments

Comment: The current schema: the main problem is that we do have many, many duplicates. The situation is as follows: we are fetching the authors from different sources, so one author can have several firstnames, lastnames, emails. It happens often that we are storing 10, 20, even 30 entries for one single author.

Comment: Proposal #1: agree this is oversized, so it seems this is not a good practice, normalize everything in order to get unique fields only and many connection tables? A big waste, you mean performance or storage, or both?

Comment: Proposal #2: Glad this is something close to the good solution. The reason why splitting first and last names is the fact an author can have firstname and lastname alternatives. Some of them may have up to 20 or 30 different alternatives as the author data is fetched from several non standardized sources. Here, you thing it is a good idea to then have one entry J.K Rowling, then another entry JK Rowling, then a third one John K. Rowling, and a fourth one John Ken Rowling, etc etc? To mention that the lastname Rowling can be used for many other authors.

Comment: The email also being possible to have multiple emails for one author, but one email belongs to one author only.

The main question that we have here: for big data (tables with 100+ million fields) is it better to keep a simplified structure - current solution, and have many duplicates. Is it better to over-standardize with many tables and no duplicates. Or we need an in-between solution - if so, a new schema proposal would be very useful.

Comment: The main goal is to have a single "id" for each "author".  Then focus on how to write code (possibly lots of code) to map a name+email to that id.  Furthermore, plan for errors -- when you map two different authors to the same id or vice versa.  In these cases, you have to go through multiple tables to "fix" the "error".

Comment: By "100+ million fields", are you referring to columns?  (I hope not).  100M rows, OK; that adds to the challenge.

Comment: Keep in mind that a database is a data store, _not_ a compute engine.  Do the mapping from name+email to id in code, not SQL.  Then plan the tables needed to support that code.

Comment: The Authors table may have id, preferred_name, preferred_email.  Other tables can have alternatives.  Keep `Authors` clean for the sake of the rest of the relations.

Comment: Thank you Rick. Would it be possible to have a schema proposal from your side?

Comment: To answer the question about the "100+ million fields", sure those are 100M+ rows.

Comment: @Miloš - I modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reduce size you could also think about splitting email addresses in two parts: 'jkrowling@' + 'gmail.com'. You could have a table where you store common email domains but seeing that over-normalization is a concern...

Comment: Hi @potato, this is really oversizing, as in that case we could store also all alphabet letters and then use IDs :)))

Comment: I think what potato is getting at is that some email providers are huge and that replacing '@gmail.com' with an id would in fact save space. Not so for the first part though.